# How to get WebAPI XML serializer to use TypeConverter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In a ASP.NET Web API project, I've got a custom type with a TypeConverter that handles the to and from for string conversions, as described here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvc-webapi.aspx

The custom type is used as a property in my model and this works great.  The json for my model object includes my custom object as the string value created from my TypeConverter.

So then I switch the request to accept XML instead and the TypeConverter is no longer invoked and my object is incorrectly serialized.

How to I get the XML serializer to utilize the TypeConverter as the JSON one does.  The article referenced made it sound like the use of TypeConverters, when present, was a predictable feature.  If it is completely at the whim of the serializer then making APIs that express data in both XML and JSON in a consistent way is nearly impossible.

---

Sample code from the article, plus a bit of context:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(LocationTypeConverter))]
public class Location
{        
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    // Parse a string into a Location object. "1,2" --> Loc(X=1,Y=2)
    public static Location TryParse(string input)
    {
        var parts = input.Split(',');
        if (parts.Length != 2)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int x,y;
        if (int.TryParse(parts[0], out x) && int.TryParse(parts[1], out y))
        {
            return new Location { X = x, Y = y };                
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1}", X, Y);
    }
}

public class LocationTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, 
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            return Location.TryParse((string) value);
        }

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Create a model with that class:

```
public class SampleModel
{
   public int One { get; set;}
   public string Two { get; set;}
   public Location Three { get; set;}
}
```

Create a ApiController with a method like this:

```
public SampleModel Get()
{
   return new SapleModel { One = 1, Two = "Two", Three = new Location { X = 111, Y = 222 } };
}
```

That's it.  Using fiddler and try them both and note that Location serializes using the converter into the single-line comma-seperated format like this (Three="111,222") with Json but not with XML.

Comment: Could you share the repro code?

Comment: Sure, i just whipped up one from that referenced article that should demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using an implicit conversion operator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx